# How to insert a comma in the following code

Tags: php, html, css

Am getting a list of HTML tags by the code below:

**Code**:

```
<?php
// Heavy testing:

ini_set('memory_limit', '400M');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('index.php')); // Don't know how to make it use the loaded document

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');

$names = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $names[] = $node->nodeName;
}

echo join(PHP_EOL, array_unique($names));
// Source: https://gist.github.com/kwoodfriend/9669711

?>
```

Output:

```
html
body
p
title
link
meta
div
article
h1
b
strong
br
hr
h2
ul
li
ol
s
cite
a
h3
```

But it needs to add a comma(`,`) in between tags.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("$names"); //read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    echo $convert[$i].', '; //write value by index
}
// Source: https://php.net/manual/it/function.file-get-contents.php#102319
?>
```

That just adds the comma at the end of the line.

The desired result is every tag starting `body` and below.(not double of the same tag: p, div, p, etc...)

```
   p, div, article, h1, b, strong, br, hr, h2, ul, li, ol, s, cite, a, h3 {

    }
```

As you can see, i also need to add some `CSS` code in between of `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer takes the following things into account:

- skip html and body
- insert comma and a space for every element
- add css braces and $css var

---

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    // skip html and body
    if($node->nodeName === 'html' or $node->nodeName === 'body') {
        continue;
    }

    // insert everything else
    $names[] = $node->nodeName;
}

$css = 'color:red;';

echo join(', ', array_unique($names)) . " {\n" . $css . "\n}\n";
```

If you have to many node elements, refine your query `$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');`
or filter/skip nodes! I'm using array_unique() here, so that every node is only once adressed.

---

Just for you the full thing :)

```
<?php

// html
$content = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome to WPИ-XM Serverpack!</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="tools/webinterface/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=tools/webinterface/">
</head>
<body bgcolor="E7E7E7" text="333333">
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Welcome to the WPИ-XM server stack!</h1>
    </div>
    <strong>You should be redirected to the administration interface of WPN-XM in 5 seconds.</strong>
    <br>
     Click <a href="tools/webinterface/">here</a> for immediate redirection.
</div>
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');

// ---- my answer ----

foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    // skip html and body
    if($node->nodeName === 'html' or $node->nodeName === 'body') {
        continue;
    }

    // insert everything else
    $names[] = $node->nodeName;
}

$css = 'color:red;';

echo join(', ', array_unique($names)) . " {\n" . $css . "\n}\n";
```

Output:

```
head, meta, title, link, div, h1, strong, br, a {
color:red;
}
```

Live @ **http://ideone.com/pMLgAC**

Comment: This outputs only the following: `{
color:red;
}`

Comment: I seriously just cop/pasted your code xD. Do i need to put it in the document itself?

Comment: I added an example for demonstration.

Comment: You sir, are awesome. It's working. Upvoted and accepted answer. Thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just implode the array?

```
$tag_string = implode(', ', $names);
echo $tag_string;
```

Comment: Working, But the output is `html, body, p, title, link, link, link, meta, meta, meta, div, article, h1, p, b, strong, br, hr, p, b, h2, ul, li, li, h2, h2, p, b, h2, ol, li, li, ul, li, s, b, li, s, b, li, ol, li, li, li, ol, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, h2, ul, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, cite, li, cite, li, cite, li, li, li, li, ul, li, li, `(etc.. too long for the comment boxy.) As you can see, it outputs dual entries of the same tag, and it also displays html, link, meta. Which are redundant for what i want to do.

Comment: I but it at the bottom of my answer: `The desired result is every tag starting body and below.(not double of the same tag: p, div, p, etc...)`. It was buried at the bottom. my bad :)